# How to ignore checksum errors in matplotlib live graph plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I keep getting errors from my DHT22 temp sensor on my Raspberry Pi 4 Raspbian distro and my live matplotlib graph crashes and shuts down everytime.
Errors: Checksum error, unplausible data, full buffer was not captured.
I would like the matplotlib to completely ignore these errors and keep ploting live. Any ideas?
Below is the code:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import board
import adafruit_dht 
import time
# Create figure for plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = []
ys = []

# Initialize communication with DHT22
if True:
    try:    
        aDHTDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D4)
    except IOError:
        print ("Error")
time.sleep(2)
# This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate(i, xs, ys):
    
    # Read temperature (Celsius) from DHT22
    temp_c = aDHTDevice.temperature
    if temp_c is not None:
    # Add x and y to lists
        xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
        ys.append(temp_c)

        # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
        xs = xs[-20:]
        ys = ys[-20:]

        # Draw x and y lists
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(xs, ys)
        time.sleep(4)
    # Format plot
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.title('DHT22 Temperature reading over Time')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (deg C)')

# Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Updated with exception

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import board
import adafruit_dht 
import time
# Create figure for plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = []
ys = []

# Initialize communication with DHT22
if True:
    try:    
        aDHTDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D4,use_pulseio=False)
    except IOError:
        print ("Error")
time.sleep(3)
# This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate(i, xs, ys):
    
    # Read temperature (Celsius) from DHT22
    temp_c = aDHTDevice.temperature
    if temp_c is not None:
    # Add x and y to lists
        xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
        ys.append(temp_c)

        # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
        xs = xs[-20:]
        ys = ys[-20:]

        # Draw x and y lists
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(xs, ys)
        time.sleep(6)
        
    except RuntimeError as error:
        print(error.args[0])
        time.sleep(1.0)
        continue
    except Exception as error:
        aDHTDevice.exit()
        raise error
    # Format plot
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.title('DHT22 Temperature reading over Time')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (deg C)')

# Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=2000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: use `try/except` inside `animate`

Comment: i tried that and still hasn't worked

Comment: if you tried it then show this code in question - maybe you used it in wrong way. if you get exception then you have to display previous value instead of new one.

Comment: BTW: in `animation` you may replace `data` in plot and then you don't have to create again label, title, etc. Why do you use `time.sleep(4)` ? You have `interval=` to control time between data.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot) in question (not comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people may help you.

Comment: what do you mean I can use ```data``` in plot in the ```animation```?

Comment: plot has function `set_data(xdata, ydata)` which replaces data in plot without redrawing it.You can see it in one of example in documentation for [animation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html)

Comment: I was able to solve this issue thanks. Used ```try/except```